# How to use strstr for string comparing

Tags: c, strstr

I am creating code that will scan the user's inputted word and compare it to that of the keyword. When scanning, it checks if the letters are in the right place, and if not, it says it isnt, but it seems to skip over whether the letter is somewhere else in the keyword using `else if(strstr(answer,&guess[i])!=NULL)` I have tried using a simple == keyword as well as used others like `strcmp`. Here is the code, and any tips would help:

```
        //if the guess is correct, it says so and terminates the program
        char j = guess[i];
        if(strcmp(guess,answer)==0){
            printf("The word you guessed was %s, and it was correct!",answer);
            return(0);
        }
        else if(answer[i] == guess[i]){
        printf("%c",j);
    }
    
    //checks to see if right letter wrong place
    else if(strstr(answer,&guess[i])!=NULL){
        
        printf("(%c)",guess[i]);
    }
    
    //prints wrong if not there
    else if(!strstr(answer,&guess[i])){
        printf("_");

    }
```

Comment: Show a [mcve] along input along with expected vs. actual output.

Comment: You use `strstr()` when you want to find the exact 'needle' string at an arbitrary position in the 'haystack' string.  You don't use it for Wordle-style searching; you have to write more specialized code for that.

Comment: Your code snippet does not show where or how the value of `i` is set. Show your full code.

Answer (score 0):

`&g[i]` is a pointer to the letter in the ith position. The problem with that is if you have a string `"Hello world"` and send the first position, the pointer `&g[1]` points to the 'e' but the function strstr is going to parse the string until it finds the special character '\0', so `&g[1]` points to the string `ello world`.
In order to solve this, you could use a linear scan iterating over all characters in the keyword string, and comparing them to what g[i] has.